# Access snapping toolbar with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gui

In PyQGIS 3 we can access the various toolbars via `iface.webToolBar()`, `iface.vectorToolBar` and so on returning `QToolBar` objects that can e.g. be shown with the `QToolBar().show()` method. Very convenient!

Attempting to access the snapping toolbar the same way, I had to realise that there is no method `iface.snappingToolBar()`:

[image]

So my question: **How to access the snapping toolbar with PyQGIS** (in Order to show or hide it programmatically e.g.?)

Answer (score 3):

Just found a way, but I still wonder why there is no convenience method:

```
>>> [t.objectName() for t in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar)]
['mBrowserToolbar', 'mFileToolBar', 'mLayerToolBar', 'mDigitizeToolBar', 'mAdvancedDigitizeToolBar', 'mMapNavToolBar', 'mAttributesToolBar', 'mPluginToolBar', 'mHelpToolBar', 'mRasterToolBar', 'mLabelToolBar', 'mVectorToolBar', 'mDatabaseToolBar', 'mWebToolBar', 'mSnappingToolBar', 'mDataSourceManagerToolBar', 'mShapeDigitizeToolBar', 'mSelectionToolBar', 'mMeshToolBar', 'mAnnotationsToolBar', 'mToolbar', 'mBookmarkToolbar', '', 'mToolbar', 'mToolbar', 'mBrowserToolbar', 'Erlangen Erweiterungen', 'BBBB Erweiterungen', 'OSMDownloader', 'QuickOSM', 'processingToolbar', '', '', '']
>>> iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'mSnappingToolBar')
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QToolBar object at 0x7fa433d1c1f0>
>>> iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'mSnappingToolBar').show()
```

... works for me.